# Android Modify colors.xml For Different Themes

Tags: android, colors, android-xml, android-theme

I want to be able to change the application main color based on user selection.

I have a colors.xml file in which I have created a color

```
<color name="myappcolor">#99CC00</color>
```

All components in the application, such as button background etc use this color for their background.

```
android:color="@color/myappcolor"
```

Is there a way I can change the color code in the **colors.xml** file depending on what option the user selects in the application.

For example changing it to so that the application color changes - I know a restart of the application may be required.

```
<color name="myappcolor">#FF0000</color>
```

If modifying **colors.xml** dynamically is not possible - could I please have other suggestions on how to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: i suggest you refer this link for the best process of maintaining states of background for corresponding theme...http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the currentSelection in `SQLite` or `SharedPreference` and `colors.xml` shoul have all the colors , based on the user choice you can dynamicaly modify the select the color. Use the `color` from storage to apply theme

Comment: Yes I have a setting preferences screen where I save the current selection. How can I use the color from storage in xml files for example I am using android:color="@color/myappcolor" in my layout files.

Comment: How many colors do you have ? if you have limited colors store integer value representing each color and switch and match color during retrieval

Answer (score 0):

Save the Resource ID of the colors in the shared preferences. Say when user presses green color, save the value `R.color.green` in shared preference for a key **userColor**. Wherever you need to set the color of user preference you set it as

`setBackgroundResource(prefs.getInt("userColor",R.color.white)`

or something like that. Then you get white color by default. However, if user selects white or blue, you get that user specified color.

Comment: Hi that makes sense but I have set the background color in the xml layout and drawable files rather than setting background colours in code.

Comment: I believe you can't. You set the Background in code. Accessing preference in XML is not possible.